# Test for repeated gets.chomp input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, control-flow

I am working in Ruby, and I am trying to test for a user's input (the variable `kid`) being the same three times.

I want my method `speak` to be called on endlessly until the user enters "BYE" three separate times when asked the three separate questions.

Right now, if the user inputs "BYE" even only for one question the entire conversation between the terminal and user ends.

Is there a way to have the program test for "BYE" being said three times, and only once said three separate times, have the conversation end?

```
kid = gets.chomp    
unless kid == "BYE"  
    speak  
end
```

I don't know if there is a really simple solution or only a complex one, but any answers help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of how many times the user has input "BYE". When that number reaches 3 you exit:

```
 byecount = 0
 while kid = gets.chomp
 case kid     
  when "BYE"
    #increase the count of bye  
    byecount +=1
    puts byecount
    break if byecount == 3
  else
    #reset our count
    byecount = 0
    speak
  end
end
```

The code resets to 0 on a non "BYE" answer.

I find a `case` statement to be very handy in situations like this when dealing with different user input, especially coupled with regular expressions.

Comment: Well OP said have the conversation end, exit does that :)   But it was meant to demonstrate how to check the input/keep state.   You can replace `exit` with `break` and it will jump out of the while loop, and thus end the conversation as well.

Comment: Fair enough, updated answer to use a break to exit the while as opposed to the exit/world stoppage.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest looking for a ruby tutorial about "loops" and "control flow".

I think the [Ruby Primer lesson at rubymonk.com](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer) may have what you need.

This example may also be helpful:

```
times = 0          # keep track of iterations
while times < 10   # repeatedly, while this condition is true
  puts "hello!"    # output "hello!"
  times += 1       # increase count of iterations
end
```

Comment: While it's important to know about loops and flow control, this really doesn't answer the question. How would you apply this to the question?

Comment: Call it an attempt to lead him to the answer rather than just code it for him. The concepts this problem addresses are introduced at the beginning of all basic programming tutorials, and I felt it was important for him to be able to find one and learn from it, rather than just give him the answer outright.

Comment: But this is an answer site... And they can determine what is important for themself.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, where it explains sometimes it's better "not to provide a complete code sample"